# Cocoa Touch- UITextView Colors

Tags: cocoa-touch

Is there an easy way to change a single characters color in a textview?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, but you'll have to resort to an undocumented method, so I suggest you do this just for fun, not for an app that you're going to sell on AppStore:

```
[theTextView setContentToHTMLString: content];
```

Here, `content` is a NSString that contains HTML markup, allowing you to assign it to something like `"<font color='red'>T</font>he first letter of this text is red and the letter <font color='green'>Z</font> here is green"`.

Comment: Will apple really reject that since its undocumented?

Comment: @shorty876 I've recently done a school project using the method, it proved more trouble than it was worth. I'd advise you to use it with care, it actually is private for a reason. As to the rejection, the use of undocumented API may be sometimes a harbinger of trouble from this point of view.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's impossible. Use a UIWebView instead, it will give you all the flexibility html has to offer.

Comment: so i would have to write it in html...But i need access to an NSArray and i dont not know html...

what about underlining it or making it stand out somehow?

Comment: @shorty: that sounds like a different question! btw, HTML is quite easy to learn, I think.